# Inducing sleep delays in Airflow backfill Dag

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, airflow-scheduler

For backfill jobs I have tried timedelta sensor, but it seem to check for Execution Time + 60 mins , instead of current time + 60 mins. 
Is there a way I can induce current time + 60 min delay for backfill jobs ?

Essentially this delay would avoid me reaching API rate limit.
Currently using below task for delay, which does not seem to work.

```
    task_id='wait',
    delta=timedelta(minutes=60),
    dag=dag
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll need your own custom Operator or Sensor and use the task instance's `start_date` attribute. Using the `start_date` is the only change you'd need to make from the `TimeDeltaSensor` in the library.

If you copy the TimeDeltaSensor source code you can override the poke method with something like:

```py
        # ...
        target_dttm = context["task_instance"].start_date
        target_dttm += self.delta
        return timezone.utcnow() > target_dttm
```

#### Added

Though reading your Question again, I see that you might just want an operator with a sleep in its execute. Or a python callable that has a sleep pattern in it and push that through the PythonOperator... something like

```py
def hit_api():
    pass

def hit_and_back_off:
    while True:
        try:
            hit_api()
        except APILimitError:
            sleep(<SOME SLEEP>)
        except e:
            raise
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution I have found is to have another DAG , which trigers scheduled backfills